# How to resolve System.InvalidOperationException. Inaccessible due to its protection level. Only public types can be processed

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to do an exercise about write and read data to file. The program have room, customer and hotel class and after i create object and give value for it, i try to serilize and write it to file in XML format but i encounter the exception above. I have try an example about this and it is running normally. Am i missing some declaration somewhere?

This is my XMLSerializer.cs:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace Assignment7
{
    class XMLSerializer
    {
        string filePath;
        public XMLSerializer(string filePath)
        {
            this.filePath = filePath;
        }


        //This generic method serializes (writes) the object of generic data type to the file.
        public string WriteXML<T>(T type)
        {
            StringBuilder feedback = new StringBuilder();
            feedback.AppendLine("Provided data is invalid!");

            if (type == null)
                return feedback.ToString();



            //Here we define an XmlSerializer object
            XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(type.GetType());

            //Here we define an XmlWriter object and define settings for it.
            XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(filePath,
                                          new XmlWriterSettings()
                                          {
                                              OmitXmlDeclaration = true,

                                              //ConformanceLevel specifies the level of conformance
                                              //(document, fragment, or automatic detection).
                                              //The default is Document.
                                              ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Auto,
                                              Indent = true

                                          });


            //Here we serialize data to the file
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, type);

            //Here we clos ehe stream
            xmlWriter.Close();

            FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(filePath);

            if (fileInfo.Exists)
            {
                feedback.Clear();
                feedback.AppendLine(fileInfo.FullName + " exists? " + fileInfo.Exists + ". Current length: " + fileInfo.Length);

            }

            return feedback.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

This is my Program.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Asignment7
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string filePath = @"D:\Study\Windows\hotel.xml";

            Room tulip = new Room("A01", "South", "Single", 20, "Small room suitable for 1 person.");
            Room lily = new Room("A11", "North", "Double", 40, "Big room for couple.");
            Room blossom = new Room("B01", "East", "President", 150, "Luxury experience room.");

            ArrayList rooms = new ArrayList { tulip, lily, blossom };

            Customer Cus1 = new Customer("Trung", "401 Voyrinkatu", "14/02", 1);
            Customer Cus2 = new Customer("Viet", "52 Handel", "14/03", 3);
            Customer Cus3 = new Customer("David", "50 Palosarentie", "28/02", 2);

            ArrayList customers = new ArrayList { Cus1, Cus2, Cus3 };

            Hotel hotel = new Hotel("Lion Head", "18-03-1999", "Korsholm 89, Vaasa", 50, rooms, customers);
            XMLSerializer xmlSerializer = new XMLSerializer(filePath);


            Console.WriteLine(xmlSerializer.WriteXML<Room>(tulip));

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

This is my Hotel.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace Assignment7
{
    [XmlRoot("hotel")]
    class Hotel
    {
        [XmlElement("name")]
        public string HotelName { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("date")]
        public string ConstructionDate { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("address")]
        public string Address { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("staff")]
        public int Staff { get; set; }

        [XmlIgnore]
        public ArrayList Rooms { get; set; }

        [XmlIgnore]
        public ArrayList Customers { get; set; }

        public Hotel() { }
        public Hotel(string name, string constructionDate, string address, int staff, ArrayList rooms, ArrayList customers)
        {
            this.HotelName = name;
            this.ConstructionDate = constructionDate;
            this.Address = address;
            this.Staff = staff;
            this.Rooms = rooms;
            this.Customers = customers;
        }
    }


}
```

This is my Room.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace Assignment7
{
    [XmlRoot("room")]
    class Room
    {
        [XmlElement("number")]
        public string RoomNumber { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("area")]
        public string Area { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("price")]
        public double PricePerNight { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public Room() { }
        public Room(string roomNumber, string area, string type, double pricePerNight, string description)
        {
            this.RoomNumber = roomNumber;
            this.Area = area;
            this.Type = type;
            this.PricePerNight = pricePerNight;
            this.Description = description;
        }
    }
}
```

This is my Customer.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace Assignment7
{
    [XmlRoot("customer")]
    class Customer
    {
        [XmlElement("name")]
        public string CustomerName
        {
            get; set;
        }
        [XmlElement("room")]
        public string RoomNumber
        {
            get; set;
        }
        [XmlElement("arrival")]
        public string ArrivalDate
        {
            get; set;
        }
        [XmlElement("length")]
        public int LengthOfStay
        {
            get; set;
        }
        
        public Customer() { }
        public Customer(string name, string roomNumber, string arrivalDate, int lengthOfStay)
        {
            this.CustomerName = name;
            this.RoomNumber = roomNumber;
            this.ArrivalDate = arrivalDate;
            this.LengthOfStay = lengthOfStay;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: you need to add public modifier in front of your class definitions